How are these わけ different from んだ here?
The speaker of this podcast is describing the extent of getting hungover a Mexican 飲み会 can be (それ refers to playing into temptation with drinking "just a little bit")

メキシコはね、それをやるだけの時間があるんですよ。
飲み会ってね、まあだいたい、どれくらいだろう、夜の７時とか８時くらいからスタートして、終わるのは次の日の朝の4時とか、3時とか、下手すると5時とかっていうこともありますよね。
で、それをホームパーティーでするのを許されるっていうのがすごく素晴らしいなと思うわけですよ。

He then speaks of several ways people get to this state of drunkenness:

クラブで朝まで踊ってワイワイ騒ぐっていうのもあるんですけども、色んな方法があるわけですよ。
その山を燃やすためにね。

He then compares this drinking culture to Japan:

だいたい日本人ってホームパーティーはやらないですよね。
朝まで飲んで大きい声で話していたら、近所の人に迷惑がかかってしまって、近所の人に嫌われてしまって、そこで生活しにくくなるっていう問題があるので、基本的に東京の居酒屋で大きい声を出して、お話をして、カラオケで歌ってっていうのを楽しむわけなんですけども、だいたいねみんな終電までには帰るんですよ。

How does the use of わけ in any of these instances from this podcast differ from んだ? I've heard as a casual sentence ender わけ can be used kind of like "...so", but I just wonder how it's differing at all from んだ here, especially because he combines わけ with んだ in the third instance.
I did transcribe this myself so if something seems off with this or if more context is needed here is the Spotify link, it lasts from 6:30-8:00.

These わけです are used to highlight relatively important points in the explanation. They are almost the same as んです or わけなんです, but わけ might convey a slightly stronger mood of "that's how it is", "I tell you" or "you know what".
(If he uses わけ three times within a minute, you might consider it one of his speaking habits. It's nothing to be concerned about, though.)
